# How to drush rsync and sql-sync on windows with Acquia-Dev?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop, drush

Answer (just to share some hours of experience):

To get rsync and sql-sync to work on remote server using Windows (w/Aquia) it is necessary to make changes to 2 files filesystem.inc and `SqlBase.php`

First delete **cygdrive/** from  `$path = preg_replace('/cygdrive/(\w):/', '/${1}', str_replace('\\', '/', $path));` in line 61 of `filesystem.inc`

and change `drush_shell_exec('gzip -d %s', $input_file)`

instead of

`drush_shell_exec('gunzip %s', $input_file)` in line 144 of `SqlBase.php`

Happy Syncing!

Answer (score 0):

0
down vote
favorite

Answer (just to share some hours of experience):

To get rsync and sql-sync to work on remote server using Windows (w/Aquia) it is necessary to make changes to 2 files filesystem.inc and SqlBase.php.

First delete cygdrive/ from $path = preg_replace('/cygdrive/(\w):/', '/${1}', str_replace('\', '/', $path)); in line 61 of filesystem.inc

and change drush_shell_exec('gzip -d %s', $input_file)

instead of

drush_shell_exec('gunzip %s', $input_file) in line 144 of SqlBase.php

Happy Syncing!